# How can I evaluate / execute a multiline R script using rjava

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am experimenting with calling **R** from within **Java** using **rjava's** `Rengine.eval()` method. I have succeeded at running a simple "hello world" script and running simple analyses as long as I keep to single line statements.

When I try to execute a multi line statement (e.g. assigning a function definition) however, I fail to find a consistent way to get it working.

According to the presenter in this Devoxx video: [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pim3HKiWRs), (at the 36:52 mark) multi scripts can be executed by evaluating each line separately. That is unless I missinterpret the code sample he shows in the slide at the aforementioned instant.

Since that approach fails me, I have written a unit test which does not show a working approach...

Can anyone with more experience shed their light on this? The behaviour for each testcase is included in the comments. (code block below)

Any help is greatly appreciated

KR

Simon

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.rosuda.JRI.RMainLoopCallbacks;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class RJavaSanityCheck {

    private static Rengine engine;


    @Test
    public void singleStatementMultiLinesMultiEval(){
        Rengine engine = getEngine();
        engine.eval("myfunc <- function(x){");
        engine.eval("z <- x");
        engine.eval("return (x)");
        engine.eval("}");
        engine.eval("print(myfunc(1))");

        //FAIL: Throws two errors:
        //  Error: object 'x' not found
        //  Error in print(myfunc(1)) : could not find function "myfunc"
    }

    @Test
    public void singleStatementMultiLinesSingleEvalWindows(){
        Rengine engine = getEngine();
        engine.eval("myfunc <- function(x){\r\nz <- x\r\nreturn(x)\r\n}\r\n");
        engine.eval("print(myfunc(1))");
        engine.end();

        //FAIL: Prints nothing and throws an error:
        //  Error in print(myfunc(1)) : could not find function "myfunc"
    }

    @Test
    public void singleStatementMultiLinesSingleEvalLinux(){
        Rengine engine = getEngine();
        engine.eval("myfunc <- function(x){\nz <- x\nreturn(x)\n}");
        engine.eval("print(myfunc(1))");
        engine.end();

        //SUCCESS: Prints 1
    }

    @Test
    public void multiStatementsMultiLineSingleEvalLinux(){
        Rengine engine = getEngine();
        engine.eval("print(\"Hello\")\nprint(\"World!\")");
        engine.end();

        //FAIL: Prints "hello" but not "world!"
    }

    @Test
    public void multiStatementsMultiLineSingleEvalWindows(){
        Rengine engine = getEngine();
        engine.eval("print(\"Hello\")\r\nprint(\"World!\")");
        engine.end();

        //FAIL: Prints nothing
    }

    @Test
    public void MultiStatementsMultiEval(){
        Rengine engine = getEngine();
        engine.eval("print(\"Hello\")");
        engine.eval("print(\"World!\")");
        engine.end();

        //SUCCESS: Prints Hello World!
    }


    private static  Rengine getEngine(){
        if (engine == null){
            if (!Rengine.versionCheck()){
                throw new RuntimeException("Version mismatch!");
            }
            engine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--vanilla"}, false, new RMainLoopCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void rWriteConsole(Rengine rengine, String s, int i) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void rBusy(Rengine rengine, int i) {
                    //Not implemented
                }

                @Override
                public String rReadConsole(Rengine rengine, String s, int i) {
                    //Not implemented
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void rShowMessage(Rengine rengine, String s) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

                @Override
                public String rChooseFile(Rengine rengine, int i) {
                    //Not implemented
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void rFlushConsole(Rengine rengine) {
                    //Not implemented
                }

                @Override
                public void rSaveHistory(Rengine rengine, String s) {
                    //Not implemented
                }

                @Override
                public void rLoadHistory(Rengine rengine, String s) {
                    //Not implemented
                }
            });
            if (!engine.waitForR()){
                throw new RuntimeException("Loading error!");
            }
        }
        return engine;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use semicolons to run multiple commands in one line in R, so I suspect it would work if you replace all the `\n` with `;` and put it all in one long string.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately executing `engine.eval("print(\"Hello\");print(\"World!\")");` only prints "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Rserve instead of rJava.

I implemented both in my work and solved my problem using rServe.

More implementation of rserve is in the link attached.

[Integrating R with Java](http://www.codophile.com/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rserve/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I definately see benefits in using rServe instead of rJava. However, with respect to this particular problem, it is more avoiding the problem than fixing it. There must be a consistent way to evaluate scripts that contain multiple statements spread over multiple lines, no?

Answer (score 0):

Something that I make do with (but isn't the most elegant solution) at the moment is the following:

```
public REXP executeFromFile(Rengine engine, File file) throws Exception {
        String fileName = file.getCanonicalPath().replace("\\", "\\\\");
        return execute(engine, "source(\""+fileName+"\")");
}
```